# Array only places items at first place of array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm making a calculator in Java and I'm trying to make it possible to add/subtract/multiply/divide more than two numbers using more than one math operator at a time. I am trying to put the numbers in different places of the array, but for some reason it puts all of the numbers at place 0. Not sure why this is happening because I made a for loop that adds one to "i" which should change the place of the array.  (Also numDisplay is the JTextField)

```
    add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                array[i] = numDisplay.getText();
                addDouble = Double.parseDouble(array[i]);
                System.out.println(array[i] + " at place " + i);
                numDisplay.setText("");
                break;
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it puts all of the numbers at place 0"? And what do you expect the `break;` at the end of the body of the `for` loop to do?

Comment: @JonSkeet What I want is every time I press the add button, is for it to add the number I'm trying to add to the array. If I remove the break, it adds zeroes to all of the other places.

Comment: You realize that each time you press the button, it's starting the loop again, right? It sounds like you should have a `List<String>` instead, then you can just use `list.add(numDisplay.getText())`

Comment: I tried a List<String> but it didn't work... How would I loop through a List<String> and add a number to each individual place?

Comment: "It didn't work" doesn't give us any information about what you tried or what happened. It's not clear what you mean by "add a number to each individual place". I thought you were trying to add a new item? It would really help if you could clarify what you're trying to do...

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry I didn't clarify I was in kind of a rush. But now I can explain a bit more. What I want is every time I click the plus button it adds the number I want to add into the array. But what is happening is it keeps on adding the number into the same place in the array but I want it to add each number into a different place in the array.

Comment: Well that's why I suggested keeping a list instead of the array - so that each time you press the button, you add a new element to the list. But then you started talking about "add[ing] a number to each individual place" which makes very little sense. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints and edit your question to be a *lot* clearer.

Comment: The real trouble is looping inside a method where you want to add one piece of data for each method call instead of looping through all of the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    ...
    break; // breaks after first iteration
}
```

You're breaking out of the loop after the very first iteration, so you'll only have one number in the array.

> I tried to remove the break but then it added zeroes to every other place automatically

You have `array[i] = numDisplay.getText();` first and then at the end of the loop you have `numDisplay.setText("");`. So on subsequent iterations it tries to convert the empty string to a double, and ends up getting zero.

> What I want is every time I press the add button, is for it to add the number I'm trying to add to the array.

A [`List<Double>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) would be better here. You can just do `list.add(someDoubleValue)` inside your event listener. Otherwise you need to keep track of the total number of elements added so far into the array and then insert a new element at the appropriate location (if there is room).

Comment: +1. I think OP confused break with continue however continue would not be necessary as it would be at the end of the loop body anyway

Comment: I tried to remove the break but then it added zeroes to every other place automatically.

Comment: What I want is for every time I press the add button for it to add the number I put in the calculator to the array.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Awesome! Thanks but one last thing. How would I loop through a list?

Comment: You can use a `for(double val : list)`. This assumes `list` is of type `List<Double>`.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @EthanCotler No problem; glad to help!